# How to extract numeric values from a string in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL Server table call Client_details, and there is a column called Client income. it is a text field. need to take Net Income RS 35000 as a number from this text. only 35000, example text like bellow,

```
INCOME GENERATION PER MONTH 
------------------------------------------
INCOME FROM RETAIL SALE OF VEGETABLE BUSINESS RS 30,000/-
INCOME FROM WHOLE  SALE OF VEGETABLE BUSINESS- RS 40,000/- 
TOTAL INCOME APPROX- RS 70,000/-
TOTAL EXPENSES- RS 35,000/-
[SALARIES, FUEL, OTHER EXPENSES] 
NET INCOME- RS 35,000/-
```

Comment: please reformat and give more Information, like will the number always be the last 5 chars?

Comment: There must be some conditions, like "NET INCOME- RS" keyword will always be there, amount always ends with "/" ?

Comment: Do you have any code example you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a scalar function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ExtractNetAmount]
(
    @FieldText varchar(1000)    
)
RETURNS varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN

    declare @Result decimal(12, 3);

    declare @netIncomeKeword varchar(100) = 'NET INCOME- RS '
    declare @temp1 varchar(100)
    declare @temp2 varchar(100)

    set @temp1 =    SUBSTRING(@FieldText, PATINDEX('%' + @netIncomeKeword +'[0-9]%', @FieldText) + LEN(@netIncomeKeword), LEN(@FieldText))
    set @temp2 =    REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@temp1,0, charindex('/', @temp1)),',','')

    set @Result = CAST(@temp2 as decimal(12, 3))

    RETURN @Result;
END
```

**Assumptions:**

1. There must have keyword `NET INCOME- RS` present in text
2. Amount always ends with `/`

**Usage:**

```
    declare @FieldText varchar(1000) = 'INCOME FROM RETAIL SALE OF VEGETABLE 
BUSINESS RS 30,000/- INCOME FROM WHOLE SALE OF VEGETABLE BUSINESS- RS 40,000/- 
TOTAL INCOME APPROX- RS 70,000/- TOTAL EXPENSES- RS 35,000/- 
[SALARIES, FUEL, OTHER EXPENSES] NET INCOME- RS 35,000/-
'
select dbo.[ExtractNetAmount](@fieldtext)
```

It only extracts `Net Income` value from whole text, i.e. `35000.000` in given example.

Comment: I want to get Final Net Income Per Month value from bellow text. only 85000. and I have a table including this kind of text fields to get the final Income value, how can i do this. using SQL.
CLIENTS INCOME DETAILS ARE AS FOLLOWS,INCOME FROM RENTED OUT SHOPS  IS RS 25,000/-AND NET INCOME FROM TEA LEAVES COLLECTING   - RS 60,000/ AND FINAL NET INCOME PER MONTH - RS 85,000/-

Comment: Use same function, just replace the keyword value from 'NET INCOME- RS ' to 'FINAL NET INCOME PER MONTH' inside the function for variable '@netIncomeKeword'

Comment: FINAL NET INCOME key word not unique for every Field, can I use like function to do this Like '%Total%Income%'

Comment: Better write another question with sample script for temp table contains few dummy records. So we can understand better and find some way to get desired output.

Comment: Might be possible we can make some changes to existing function, or we have to write another function altogether. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server it is always better to go for replace when you are sure that the value will have this pattern

```
select cast(replace(replace(replace( 'RS 35,000/','RS',''),',',''),'/','') as 
numeric(18,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Patindex we can extract the numeric value

```
Declare @String TABLE (INCOME_GENERATION_PER_MONTH nvarchar(max))

INSERT INTO @String

SELECT 'INCOME FROM RETAIL SALE OF VEGETABLE BUSINESS RS 30,000/-'   UNION ALL
SELECT 'INCOME FROM WHOLE  SALE OF VEGETABLE BUSINESS- RS 40,000/-'  UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL INCOME APPROX- RS 70,000/-'                            UNION ALL
SELECT 'TOTAL EXPENSES- RS 35,000/-'                                 UNION ALL
SELECT '[SALARIES, FUEL, OTHER EXPENSES]'                            UNION ALL
SELECT 'NET INCOME- RS 35,000/-'

SELECT
  'Rs.' + CAST(CONVERT(varchar, CAST(INCOME_GENERATION_PER_MONTH AS Money), 0) AS varchar) + '/-' AS INCOME_GENERATION_PER_MONTH
FROM (SELECT
  REPLACE(REPLACE((SUBSTRING(INCOME_GENERATION_PER_MONTH, PATINDEX('%[^[A-Z -]%', INCOME_GENERATION_PER_MONTH), LEN(INCOME_GENERATION_PER_MONTH))), '/-', ''), ',', '') AS INCOME_GENERATION_PER_MONTH,
  ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(REPLACE((SUBSTRING(INCOME_GENERATION_PER_MONTH, PATINDEX('%[^[A-Z -]%', INCOME_GENERATION_PER_MONTH), LEN(INCOME_GENERATION_PER_MONTH))), '/-', ''), ',', '')) AS ISnumericval
FROM @String) dt
WHERE dt.ISnumericval = 1
```

Result

```
INCOME_GENERATION_PER_MONTH
----------------------------
Rs.30000.00/-
Rs.40000.00/-
Rs.70000.00/-
Rs.35000.00/-
Rs.35000.00/-
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it with some string manipulation assuming the characters around the value are always present and standard in the way you have posted your sample data. You can run the below and modify it if there are any other cases you need to deal with for testing purposes:

```
CREATE TABLE #income (clientIncome NVARCHAR(200));

INSERT INTO #income
(
    clientIncome
)
VALUES ('INCOME FROM RETAIL SALE OF VEGETABLE BUSINESS RS 30,000/-'),
('INCOME FROM WHOLE  SALE OF VEGETABLE BUSINESS- RS 40,000/-'),
('TOTAL INCOME APPROX- RS 70,000/-'),
('TOTAL EXPENSES- RS 35,000/-'),
('[SALARIES, FUEL, OTHER EXPENSES]'),
('NET INCOME- RS 35,000/-');

SELECT i.clientIncome,
       CASE
           WHEN CHARINDEX('RS ', i.clientIncome) != 0 THEN
               CAST(replace(SUBSTRING(
                    i.clientIncome,
                    CHARINDEX('RS ', i.clientIncome) + 3,
                    CHARINDEX('/-', i.clientIncome) - CHARINDEX('RS ', i.clientIncome) - 3
                    ),',','') AS NUMERIC)
           ELSE
               NULL
       END income
FROM #income AS i;

DROP TABLE #income;
```

**Produces:**

```
clientIncome                                                income
INCOME FROM RETAIL SALE OF VEGETABLE BUSINESS RS 30,000/-   30000
INCOME FROM WHOLE  SALE OF VEGETABLE BUSINESS- RS 40,000/-  40000
TOTAL INCOME APPROX- RS 70,000/-                            70000
TOTAL EXPENSES- RS 35,000/-                                 35000
[SALARIES, FUEL, OTHER EXPENSES]                            NULL
NET INCOME- RS 35,000/-                                     35000
```

This will extract the value, remove the comma and cast to numeric for you.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
DECLARE @value NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @value = N'RS 35,000/ASDF' --anything your value is

WHILE PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @value) > 0 
SET @value = REPLACE(@value, SUBSTRING(@value, PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @value), 1), '' ) 

SELECT @value
```